# Allow input number only, else show message

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

Allowing the user to input number only is working.

But if the user tries to enter something other than number it must show message.

I have tried Validators with pattern, but I can't make the message show.

How to show error message when user doesn't enter a number?

Reference:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers-vewaxf?file=src/app/only-number.directive.ts

.html file

```
<h3>Template Driven Form</h3>
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input name="number" type="text" onlyNumber [(ngModel)]="number" />
  <p>model value: {{ number }}</p>
  <p>form dirty: {{ form.dirty }}</p>
</form>

<h3>Reactive Form</h3>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input formControlName="number" type="text" onlyNumber />
  <p>model value: {{ formGroup.get('number').value }}</p>
  <p>form dirty: {{ formGroup.dirty }}</p>
  <!-- <div *ngIf="methoddd()">Sorry</div>
</form> -->
</form>
```

.ts file

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[onlyNumber]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => OnlyNumberDirective),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private onChange: (val: string) => void;
    private onTouched: () => void;
    private value: string;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {
    }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
    onInputChange(value: string) {
        const filteredValue: string = filterValue(value);
        this.updateTextInput(filteredValue, this.value !== filteredValue);
    }

    @HostListener('blur')
    onBlur() {
        this.onTouched();
    }

    private updateTextInput(value: string, propagateChange: boolean) {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
        if (propagateChange) {
            this.onChange(value);
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    // ControlValueAccessor Interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        value = value ? String(value) : '';
        this.updateTextInput(value, false);
    }
}

function filterValue(value): string {
    return value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive, you need to get references to form control via `ngModel` and `ngControl`, and then you need to set errors manually, and also you need to set previous value to form control to prevent it from changing.

In general, this is a job for custom validators, not a directive.

Try this:

```
<h3>Template Driven Form</h3>
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input name="number" type="text" onlyNumber [(ngModel)]="number" />
  <div *ngIf="!form.valid">{{form.controls.number.errors| json}}</div>
  <p>form dirty: {{ form.dirty }}</p>
</form>

<h3>Reactive Form</h3>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input formControlName="number" type="text" onlyNumber />
  <p>model err: {{ formGroup.get('number').errors | json }}</p>  
  <p>model value: {{ formGroup.get('number').value }}</p>
  <p>form dirty: {{ formGroup.dirty }}</p>
 
</form>
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {  NgControl, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[onlyNumber]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective  {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef,private control : NgControl, private ngModel: NgModel) {
    }  
    @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onChange($event: any) {

        const initialValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    
        const newValue = initialValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');

        if ( initialValue !== newValue) {

            $event.stopPropagation();
            this.control.control.setValue(newValue)
            this.control.control.setErrors({'err': 'only numbers allowed'});
            this.ngModel.control.setErrors({'err': 'only numbers allowed'});
        }
      }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers-3dpqav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fonly-number.directive.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use input type attribute to specify that it will accept only numbers:

```html
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numberValue">
```

Or if  you want to do it by a directive:

```js
@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event: any) {
    const initialValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    this.el.nativeElement.value = initialValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if ( initialValue !== this.el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-directive-m4quzk?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Have same output but need a message if user try to input non-number.

Comment: For validation messages could you use same regex but in formcontrol